# Android Development: Proper way of creating Splash Screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

I know that this has been asked several times but I really want to know the proper way of implementing an Android Splash Screen.

**1.** Should we create an XML Layout and add Runnable Java code in SplashActivity?

**2.** Or, just make an xml file in drawable and call it under Styles.xml?

I've tried both. But for me, #1 is more difficult for a beginner.

Now, I'm currently working on a splash screen using approach #2. I have made a splashstyle.xml under Drawable
[image]

Now, I called it under Styles.xml with style name SplashTheme.

[image]

Updated my AndroidManifest file.

[image]

Then, here's my SplashActivity.java. Notice that I didn't have runnable code on this class. Just a simple Intent.

[image]

And now, here's the final output. Since this is just a practice. Don't expect a nice splash screen.

[image]

**Question1:** Now, I want to adjust the image on my splash screen. Adjust it's size. How am i gonna do that since I'm not using an xml layout?

**Question2:** I want to put a text at the bottom of my splash screen. How am i gonna do that? Is there a way to add text just using the splashstyle.xml or styles.xml?

**Question3:** I have observed that my splash screen don't display for too long. Is it because my app doesn't have more contents yet? I want the splash screen to display for maybe 3-5 seconds. How am i gonna do that without implementing runnable?

Comment: whats the problem with using xml?

Comment: To answer your question 1 and 2, you can use a normal layout resource file and define your design content there. For your question 3, if you want to delay your login activity, you will have to use a handler and post a delayed runnable.

Comment: [Only ask a single question per question, click this text to find out why.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post)

Comment: [Never post pictures of text when you can post the actual text. Be sure that it is properly formatted and readable.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 4):

q1.If image size is big we can reduce size like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"></item>

    <item
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp"
        android:top="20dp"
        android:bottom="20dp">

        <bitmap

            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/delete"></bitmap>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add text in my splash screen just using splashstyle.xml? Or i really need to create a view

Comment: I think that is not possible.I referred that but i did not get any solution for that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

SplashActivity

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    final private Context mContext = SplashActivity.this;
    final private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3500;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

    /* remove call back in on destroy */
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (handler != null) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /* device back button click event */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (handler != null) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

activity_splash.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.packagename">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".Halt">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer for your Question 3: I have observed that my splash screen don't display for too long. Is it because my app doesn't have more contents yet? I want the splash screen to display for maybe 3-5 seconds. How am i gonna do that without implementing runnable?

You need to create a class which extends Application and use sleep method to display a splash screen for some seconds.

Example:

Halt.java

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class Halt extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SystemClock.sleep(2500);
  }
}
```

After this class you need to declare Halt class like this: **android:name=".Halt"** in your manifest file in  **application** tag. Like this:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.splashdemo">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".Halt">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".OtherActivity"/>
</application>
```

This will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

For

> Question1: Now, I want to adjust the image on my splash screen. Adjust it's size. How am i gonna do that since I'm not using an xml layout?
>
> Question2: I want to put a text at the bottom of my splash screen. How
>   am i gonna do that? Is there a way to add text just using the
>   splashstyle.xml or styles.xml?

You can't do all things using style.xml it can't create view for your activity it just for enhance your View. Use xml layout for your activity or dynamically add views to your activity.

> Question3: I have observed that my splash screen don't display for too long. Is it because my app doesn't have more contents yet? I want the splash screen to display for maybe 3-5 seconds. How am i gonna do that without implementing runnable?

splash screen don't display for too long because in your `onCreate()` contains starting LoginActivity so when `onCreate()` called it start your LoginActivity. If you want to control the delay you can use Handler,runnable,Timer task etc.