# Xamarin - Splash Screen showing gray background instead of white

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-5

I'm trying the Xamarin Forms application that I developed on my mobile phone which is in dark mode.

I don't know if that has to do with it but I set the background color of my Splash Screen to white. Here's the `splash_screen.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/launcher_background"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap 
            android:src="@drawable/logo1_100x153"
            android:tileMode="disabled"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And then on the style I added `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as I have on my `MainTheme` because I don't what the dark mode to affect the colors on my app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- As of Xamarin.Forms 4.6 the theme has moved into the Forms binary -->
    <!-- If you want to override anything you can do that here. -->
    <!-- Underneath are a couple of entries to get you started. -->

    <!-- Set theme colors from https://aka.ms/material-colors -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <!--<item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>-->
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <!--<item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>-->
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
      <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

And then here's how it shows on my phone

[image]

Does someone know how to fix this? Please help and thanks.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve The background of the xml that sets the background is this one `<color android:color="@color/launcher_background"/>` if I set it to red the background of the splash screen will be red

Comment: I'm not finding `<color` as an option in docs, or other examples - but that could just be me. Maybe do color via a drawable, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/48335137/199364: `<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"></item>` If you get that to work, go ahead and add the fixed code as "Your Answer" below.

Comment: What's the value of `launcher_background` in your `colors.xml` file? How can we reproduce this problem?I did a test, but I couldn't reproduce this problem while  setting `launcher_background` to `#FFFFFF` on my side.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT It's white. I already changed it to #FFFFFF just in case but same error occurs

Comment: If it is convinient for you, could you please post a basic demo so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the colour directly?

```
<color android:color="@android:color/black"/>
```

full code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap 
            android:src="@drawable/logo1_100x153"
            android:tileMode="disabled"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```